# Multiple embedded collections type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have 3 entities, Product, ProductOption and ProductImage.

Product is One to Many ProductOption and ProductOption is One to Many ProductImage.

In my ProductType I have a CollectionType for entry_type ProductOptionType.
In my ProductOptionType I have a CollectionType for entry_type ProductImageType.

So I have multiple embedded collections here and I don't know how to show the form ProductImageType in the view. For now I have this :

```
// {{ form.start(form) }}
// {{ form.errors(form) }}
// other form fields

{{ form.label(form.product_option, "Options") }}
{{ form.errors(form.product_option) }}
{{ form.widget(form.product_option) }}
<a href="#" id="add_options">Add options</a>

// Some javascript to handle add_options
```

Here is the ProductType :

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('price', MoneyType::class)
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:ProductCategory',
                'choice_label' => 'code',
            ))
            ->add('genre', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:ProductGenre',
                'choice_label' => 'code',
            ))
            ->add('product_option', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => ProductOptionType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_product';
    }
}
```

ProductOptionType :

```
class ProductOptionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('product_size', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:ProductSize',
                'choice_label' => 'code',
            ))
            ->add('product_color', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:ProductColor',
                'choice_label' => 'code',
            ))
            ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('enabled', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('images', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => ProductImageType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
            ->add('print_zones', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'Face' => 'face',
                    'Dos' => 'dos',
                    'Manche droite' => 'manche_droite',
                    'Manche gauche' => 'manche_gauche',
                ),
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => ProductOption::class,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_product_option';
    }
}
```

And the ProductImageType :

```
class ProductImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, array(
                'label' => "Sélectionnez une image",
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => ProductImage::class,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_product_image';
    }
}
```

My form.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.name, "Nom") }}
    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.description, "Description") }}
    {{ form_errors(form.description) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.description) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.price, "Prix") }}
    {{ form_errors(form.price) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.price) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.category, "Catégorie") }}
    {{ form_errors(form.category) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.category) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.genre, "Sexe") }}
    {{ form_errors(form.genre) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.genre) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.product_option, "Ajoutez une ou plusieurs variantes") }}
    {{ form_errors(form.product_option) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.product_option) }}
    <a href="#" id="add_variante" class="btn btn-default">Ajouter une variante</a>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}}) }}
</div>

{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('div#appbundle_product_product_option');
    var index = $container.find(':input').length;
    $('#add_variante').click(function(e) {
        addVariante($container);
        e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
        return false;
    });
    if (index == 0) {
        addVariante($container);
    } else {
        if(!document.getElementsByClassName('form-checkbox')){
            $container.children('div').each(function() {
                addDeleteLink($(this));
            });
        }
    }
    function addVariante($container) {
        var template = $container.attr('data-prototype')
            .replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Variante n°' + (index+1))
            .replace(/__name__/g,        index)
        ;
        var $prototype = $(template);
        addDeleteLink($prototype);
        $container.append($prototype);
        index++;
    }
    function addDeleteLink($prototype) {
        var $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>');
        $prototype.append($deleteLink);
        $deleteLink.click(function(e) {
            $prototype.remove();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the form builder would help

Comment: added the form types :-)

Comment: got some error ? what isn't working ?

Comment: Well the form ProductType and ProductOptionType is showing but ProductImageType does not show up. I'm gonna add my form.html.twig.